# turtlebot bad gyro calibration (also)

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-calibration, gyro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there.
I read the post from the other gentleman that was having bad gyro calibration issues, but the thread did not seem to be same issue as mine so starting new thread.
I have ran the calibration steps, create stopped facing the wall where it started, I created my own launch file basically identical to the one on the tutorial, except using my calibration values.
However even when I start up my turtlebot with the new custom gyro and odom compensation settings, I still get a diagnostic error in the dashboard that says. Gyro Sensor: Bad Gyro Calibration.
Gyro enabled= true, raw gyro rate = 8 calibration offset = 8

Of course when I try to do room mapping of a basic hallway, the map is just a jumble and is all over the place. Any suggestions for how to troubleshoot would be appreciated.
Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11130/turtlebot-bad-gyro-calibration-(also)/) by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 693 on 2011-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your gyro is returning values of 8 for the raw gyro rate then you may have the same problem as the other post. Changing the calibration values will not cause the gyro to return values of 8 for the raw values. This most likely means that the gyro is not powered and the irobot create is reading the noise on the line.

One of three senarios can cause the gyro not to be powered:

1. The irobot create did not power on correctly. Try power cycling the irobot create.
2. The power board is not seated properly. Try pressing down on the power board to make sure it is properly seated on the connector.
3. There is an electrical problem with the power board or irobot create. Try following the steps listed in this question http://answers.ros.org/question/2024/turtlebot-bad-gyro-calibration

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-07**:
did you determine whether the irobot create is outputting 5V on pin 8? Any brand new functional create should do this. There is nothing special that we do to the create.. We typically ship the create in the box it came in to the customer. but we have seen malfunctioning creates that shipped damaged.

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2011-09-07**:
That said...I am concerned about ordering a replacement Create from iRobot if it has not been certified to be up to ROS specs. I would rather not buy an entire new turtlebot when I have most of the parts just to get a good Create. Any suggestions?

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2011-09-07**:
No I did not. I already had a Create and was buying the parts seperately to build it up. That said I would likely be in the market for the Create portion that would come with certification on specs if mine does not work.

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-07**:
@Scott did you get your TB from Willow Garage? If you did get it from Willow Garage can you post the serial number of your power board so I can look up the qualification information for the board?

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2011-09-07**:
I did the reseating and recycling. Did not seem to help much. Interestingly,after recycle, raw gyro value was 6, but over span of about 20 minutes, it went from 6 to 7 and to 8 again. I will check the voltage levels today and post results. What is the typical raw gyro value that you most often see?

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-09-06**:
no, the power to the gyro is always on when the create is on. The irobot create provides a 5V on pin 8 as long as the create is on. Breaker 0 on the dashboard sets the digital out to high which enables the voltage regulator on the power board supplying power to the kinect camera.

**Comment by [Scott](https://answers.ros.org/users/100/scott/) on 2011-09-06**:
Thanks Melanie, is there pehaps a software setting that sends power to the gyro like you have for the breaker "0" on the turtlebot dashboard?